# Optimize Spring RestControllerAdvice with multiple exceptions

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, controller-advice

I have around 20 to 30 different types of different Exceptions all extending Exception class in Java. 
one example is:

```
public class NoHandlerFoundException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9079454849611061074L;

public NoHandlerFoundException() {
    super();
}

public NoHandlerFoundException(final String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

}

Other example is:

```
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends Exception{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9079454849611061074L;

public ResourceNotFoundException() {
    super();
}

public ResourceNotFoundException(final String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

}

and many more.
As you can see most of the code is repeated and then I use ControllerAdvice like (I know code in ControllerAdvice argument exception class should be proper):

```
@ExceptionHandler({NoHandlerFoundException.class, ResourceNotFoundException.class})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public @ResponseBody ExceptionResponse handleResourceNotFound(final NoHandlerFoundException exception,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {

    ExceptionResponse error = new ExceptionResponse();
    error.setErrorMessage(exception.getMessage());
    error.callerURL(request.getRequestURI());

    return error;
}
```

So I want to know if we have any way in which I can optimize above exceptions and not write individual classes doing almost same job n times of times but still want to differentiate between them.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach to reduce code redundancy.

```
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {NoHandlerFoundException.class, ResourceNotFoundException.class})
protected ResponseEntity handleInvalidDataException(RuntimeException exception, WebRequest request) {

    ExceptionResponse error = new ExceptionResponse();
    error.setErrorMessage(exception.getMessage());
    error.callerURL(request.getRequestURI());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```